# ARCore Augmented Image how to create a new Object Renderer at runtime

Tags: android, opengl-es, arcore

I'm expanding the "Augmented Image" Arcore project in Android Studio using Java, and i would like to create at runtime new Objects Renderer in order to spawn new objects on the augmented Image. I saw the "Hello AR" project, but in that example it creates more instances of the same object, and therefore use the same Object Renderer. I need to create different objects and so I think I need to create different Objects Renderers.

I tried to create all of the Object Renderers I need in the "createOnGlThread" method but it takes time, while i'd prefer to create them at runtime. The problem it gives me is in the shader tho. It can't create them outside the "createOnGlThread" method as the "GLES20.glCreateShader(type)" method in the ShaderUtil always returns 0, and "GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);" returns 0 in the compileStatus too and it launches the RuntimeException("Error creating shader.").

How can I create an Object Renderer outside the "createOnGlThread" method?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is instead of creating all you Object Renderers at first try to create them when for example a model has been selected.
let's say you have a button on the screen and when you click on the button you want to create a new Object Renderers and change the model and texture. here is how you can handle this.

```
myNewModel.setOnClickListener {
            objectName = "newModelFromAssets"
            objectTexture ="newTextureFromAssets"
            objectRenderer = ObjectRenderer()
            isModelSelected = true
    }
```

Then in onDrawFrame do this:

```
if (isModelSelected) {
            isModelSelected = false
            try {
                objectRenderer.createOnGlThread(
                    this,
                    objectName,
                    objectTexture
                )
               objectRenderer.setDepthTexture(
                    depthTexture.depthTexture,
                    depthTexture.depthWidth,
                    depthTexture.depthHeight
                )
               objectRenderer.setMaterialProperties(
                    0.0f,
                    2.0f,
                    0.5f,
                    6.0f
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("onSurfaceCreated", "Failed to read plane texture")
            }
        }
```

That's all.

And an easier solution is to use 'queueEvent' to interact with OPENGL from main thread like this :

```
surfaceView.queueEvent {
//render your object
}
```